# In wordpress the main theme template is not working on my child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming, child-theming

I was working on my child theme for my client project in posedion theme and there is a slider which i try to inherit from main theme name template-slider.php in my fornt-page.php i use get_template_part('template-slider')

it show the page title but not the slider
[image: Homepage]

Here is code picture

[image]

[image]

I try to get slider but i got the homepage title which I haven't call